# Garbage collection takes a long time in case of huge objects

Tags: node.js, garbage-collection

I have a Node.js app which does a real-time messaging between Redis Pubsub and Websockets. The application deals with strings that are of huge length going to around 2.5 MB in each individual message. It performs fine, except when GC starts. Here is what I see with the `-trace_gc` flag turned on:

```
[GC interrupt] [GC in old space requested].
[29290:0x35826f0] 104218566 ms: Mark-sweep 104.2 (1139.5) -> 20.7 (1057.8) MB, 153.4 / 0 ms (+ 19.4 ms in 16 steps since start of marking, biggest step 17.0 ms) [GC interrupt] [GC in old space requested].
[29290:0x35826f0] 104219639 ms: Mark-sweep 110.8 (1146.0) -> 110.1 (1146.0) MB, 20.1 / 0 ms (+ 63.3 ms in 25 steps since start of marking, biggest step 59.0 ms) [GC interrupt] [GC in old space requested].
[29290:0x35826f0] Increasing marking speed to 3 due to high promotion rate
[29290:0x35826f0] 104222147 ms: Mark-sweep 384.7 (1415.3) -> 128.1 (1163.8) MB, 390.0 / 0 ms (+ 19.9 ms in 27 steps since start of marking, biggest step 17.0 ms) [GC interrupt] [GC in old space requested].
[29290:0x35826f0] 104224639 ms: Mark-sweep 394.0 (1424.5) -> 48.0 (1084.9) MB, 324.0 / 0 ms (+ 22.7 ms in 10 steps since start of marking, biggest step 17.0 ms) [GC interrupt] [GC in old space requested].
[29290:0x35826f0] 104225695 ms: Mark-sweep 175.1 (1209.9) -> 88.2 (1124.0) MB, 169.0 / 0 ms (+ 18.3 ms in 11 steps since start of marking, biggest step 16.3 ms) [GC interrupt] [GC in old space requested].
```

Here is what I have tried:

1. Running node with `--expose-gc` flag and manually calling GC every minute. Didn't help much in this case.
2. I have increased the old space size to 3GB with `--max-old-space-size=3072`. This decreased the frequency at which the app gets stuck in GC, but I cannot keep increasing the memory indefinitely.

Somethings that I have gathered by reading from various places is that, I am running out of free space in the old objects region, so V8 triggers the full  marks and sweep collection which takes a long time. Since my app deal with large objects (mostly JS strings), they are perhaps put in the old space directly.

What are the things that can be done to minimize the GC time? Note that the app exchanges a lot of messages and cutting up the strings so that they each have less length is a non-option.

Comment: You should avoid allocating these big strings in the first place, and instead stream all the I/O using the built-in pipes and `Buffer`s.

Comment: @OrangeDog yes, big strings are an issue, but that would require a lot of changes in the architecture, because they are coming from Redis via pubsub. So I was looking for other better solutions if possible. :)

Comment: Find a better Redis Node module that supports streams. Fiddling with the GC is not going to help your performance.